# Autopilot with vCSA 5.5 issues

Tags: vmware, maas, openstack-autopilot

i'm trying to find the reason why i have the following error while adding new nodes under MAAS. (Failed to query node's BMC - Power state could not be queried: vmware failed with return code 1: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '://10.1.232.20://sdk/vimServiceVersions.xml'). I'm trying to add 4 nodes (VMS) that are required to build the openstack, but MaaS is generating errors.

The vcenter is a vcSA 5.5 running on a ESXi 5.5 host. The autopilot VM is able to ping the vcenter. I've also tested with IE from my workstation to validate if the XML is available.

Maybe you can give me a clue where to look? I'm new to autopilot and MaaS.  Are there any logs files that could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I would like also to add that i'm following the procedure from : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-autopilot-testdrive

Comment: Can you manually go to MAAS and add your vmware nodes with "Add chassis"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had to upadate the autopilot vm with the command : apt-get update && apt-get upgrade.

The initial version has bugs.